# Flow question - how to send email alert to opportunity owner

Tags: visual-workflow, email-alert

I've built out a flow which checks 3 fields as condition to run, I need it to send an email alert to the opportunity owner if the flow is triggered.

Not sure how to set this up, I can only add users on email alerts, how do I add the opportunity owner field to the email alert to send an alert to the owner of the triggered record?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please give us snippets/screenshots of what you have already tried.

Comment: @NedlaV please see screenshots

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to set the 'Recipient Address List' rather than the Recipient ID. That attribute accepts a comma separated list of emails so you can just use the `{!Record.Owner.Email}` notation that you've used to try and set the Recipient ID attribute. You should also use a Get Records element to retrieve the Email Template ID as the current set up in your screenshot will break when you deploy it between environments.

An alternative approach is to use an [Email Alert](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_wfalerts.htm&type=5) rather than the Send Email Action. The configuration for this means that you only need to pass it the Opportunity ID from your Flow. This might be a good option if you don't need to log the email that's sent against the Opportunity.

There's an example of both of these approaches in this blog post (although the Send Email approach doesn't use an email template):

[How to send email using flow in Salesforce](https://viewonreview.com/how-to-send-email-using-flow-in-salesforce/)